# Convert a given array of integers to a sorted one, by deleting the minimum number of elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am working on the following problem:

I have to convert a given array of integers to a sorted one, by deleting the minimum number of elements.

For example: [3,5,2,10,11]  will be sorted by deleting ‘2‘ : [3,5,10,11].
Or [3,6,2,4,5,7,7]  will be sorted by deleting ‘3‘,’6‘ : [2,4,5,7,7] OR by deleting ‘6‘,’2‘ : [3,4,5,7,7] (both ways i remove 2 elements, that’s why they are both correct).

My thought was to keep a counter for each element to see how many conflicts it has with other elements.
What i mean by conflicts: in the first example, numbers ‘3‘ and ‘5‘ have 1 conflict each (with the number ‘2‘) and number ‘2‘ has 2 conflicts (with numbers ‘3‘ and ‘5‘).
So, after calculating the array of conflicts, i remove from the original array the element that has the max number of conflicts and i repeat for the remaining array until all elements have 0 conflicts.

This is not an efficient way though (in some cases that i havent thought it might also produce wrong results), so i was wondering if anyone could think of a better solution.

Comment: It smells like a programming competition problem. Is it?

Comment: No, it isn't (not even sure what you mean). It is a small part of a project me and my team have at college.

Comment: NP, and not trying to offend in any way, just wanted more information on the motivation because it might affect possible answers (more/less educational or more/less practical for example)

Comment: It's ok, no offence taken. I'm looking for a practical answer i guess, since it's about a programming project (the tools i use are not important, the idea/algorithm is what bothers me at most).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is just a cleverly disguised version of the **[longest increasing subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).** If you delete the minimum number of elements to have a sorted sequence, what you're left with is the longest increasing subsequence of the original array.  Accordingly, you can do the following:

1. Find the longest increasing subsequence (O(n log n) algorithms exist for this), then
2. Delete everything not in that subsequence.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can build a DAG based on the elements in the array:

- Each element a[n] is a vertex.
- For any pair of elements (m,n) where (m < n) and (a[m] <= a[n]) add a directed edge.

  Optimization: you can build simple chains for sorted subarrays. For example, if a[m]<=a[m+1)<=a[m+2]<=a[m+3]>a[m+4], you can skip adding the edges (m,m+2) and (m,m+3) for vertex m.

The goal now is to find the [longest path in the graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which has a linear time solution for directed acyclic graphs.

A  algorithm is described in the aforementioned Wikipedia page and also [here](http://moodle.bracu.ac.bd/pluginfile.php/4784/mod_resource/content/1/longest-path-in-dag.pdf).

Comment: This will certainly work, but notice that the overall time is O(n^2), because the longest path in a DAG is linear in the number of *edges*, and there are O(n^2) of these.

Comment: This works and does so correctly in O(n^2) time, but I think it's possible to solve this in O(n log n).

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'm not sure it is O(n^2) given my optimization. Anyway, your solution is more efficient.

Comment: That's a cool optimization!  However, I think if you make the array alternate between elements that are bigger and smaller than one another that this will still make O(n^2) links, though with a lower constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with recursive programming. Here is my pseudo code :

```
/**
 *  sortedArray : an array already sorted.
 *  leftToSort : an unsorted array that need to be sorted/merged with sortedArray.
 *  first call to this function must be sortArrayByRemoval([], arrayToSort);
**/
public Integer[] sortArrayByRemoval(Integer[] sortedArray, Integer[] leftToSort){
    if(leftToSort.size==0){ 
        return sortedArray; //end of recursion
    }
    Integer candidate = leftToSort[0]; 
    if(candidate>=sortedArray[last]){ //append candidate to the sorted array
        return sortArrayByRemoval(sortedArray.append(candidate) , leftToSort.removeFirst());
    }else{
        //either we skip it
        Integer[] result1 = sortArrayByRemoval(sortedArray,leftToSort.removeFirst());
        //either we do back tracking
        Integer[] result2 = sortArrayByRemoval(sortedArray.removeLast(),leftToSort);
        //and finally we return the best choice (i.e. the longest array)
        return biggestArray(result1, result2);
    }
}
```

Maybe not the most efficient, but I think it gives you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck on the idea of literally deleting things from the original array, then what you want is the longest increasing subsequence of your original sequence of numbers.  This is a well-known, classic problem and you can find many examples in the literature or in textbooks.

(If you are stuck on deleting, well... find the LCS and delete everything not in the LCS.)

Comment: Ninja'd by @templatetypedef